# How to have more menu items in Windows 11 when right clicking Taskbar?

Tags: windows, taskbar, context-menu, windows-11

When I right click Windows 11 Taskbar, only one context menu item shows up: Taskbar Settings
In Windows 10 there was many other context menu item, for example Task Manager, etc.

I've tried shift, ctrl, alt right click still one single context menu item.

I do know, that context menus are different in Windows 11, now there are limited and full versions, but this feature seems something else, because no further option to click to show more items, what are available for example in desktop context menu.

**Question**

How to have more menu items in Windows 11 when right clicking Taskbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows 10 Right Click Context features on the Windows 11 Task Bar have been completely eliminated.

I think what you are seeing is the variable context appearance hovering over icons on the Task Bar.

If you want more icons that fit on your Task Bar, you need to use the Task Bar Corner Overflow feature. With this feature, you choose what icons you want to be always visible on the Task Bar and what icon will be available at the corner.

Right Click on a blank area of the Task Bar, select Task Bar settings. Look at and Set (a) Task Bar corner icons and (b) Task Bar corner overflow.

This is the new paradigm and behavior of the Windows 11 Task Bar.

Comment: Many thanks.. Only one menu item is missing me: Task Manager. Is there any alternative to get it with two clicks? (OK, I can use ctrl alt del, then click, but that involves keyboard)

Comment: In Settings, use All Apps and scroll down for Windows Tools. Right Click and Pin Windows Tools to the Start Menu.  Now go back to Start and open Windows Tools. Right Click on Task Manager and select Pin to Taskbar. Once set up TM is on the Task Bar and you do not need to use Ctrl Alt Del, This works

Answer (score 4):

Right click on the start menu icon on the taskbar. You will see task manager as well as other menu items.

Comment: cool, thx.......